# How does the official `hylang/hy' repo run its pytests on its native / `.hy' files?

Tags: hy

Is a custom plugin used, such as [pytest-hylang](https://github.com/arjaz/pytest-hylang) or [hytest](https://github.com/vodik/hytest)?

Comment: If this question is interpreted as something more like "How do I run Hy tests with pytest?", it's a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/62718382. If it's more of a question about a particular codebase than about how to do something, I would guess it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah, yes; that's it. Thanks for the help! Do I delete this question, or leave it up, or...?

Comment: Got it; thanks for all the help! If anyone needs it, I created a plugin based on the official `conftest.py`: https://github.com/syvlorg/pytest-hy